# Finding largest and smallest numbers using atoi

Tags: c, command-line, max, min, atoi

```
    scanf("%1c%2c %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",
          &x, &y, &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2], &arr[3], &arr[4],
          &arr[5], &arr[6], &arr[7], &arr[8], &arr[9]);
    strcpy(string, x);
    value1 = atoi(string);

    strcpy(string, y);
    value2 = atoi(string);

    value_final = value1 + value2;
```

I'm trying to get the ascii values for the `-l` or `-s` then pass them through the `switch` with the ascii values added but I'm getting errors when I use `atoi` and I'm not sure as to if you are supposed to be adding the ascii values when the user enters the `-l` or `-s` or if their is another way to do this?

Comment: Unintialised variables `min` and `max`. Undefined behaviour.

Comment: `strcpy(string, x);` .... what did the compiler say about that?

Comment: How about `if(x == '-' && y == 'l') {...` also the `scanf` should be `scanf("%c%c%d%d...)`

Comment: That is because you need to pass 0-terminated char arrays to the string handling functions. I don't know why you are messing around with all that when you just test the characters entered directly. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several problems:

- **Major:** the `switch` cases do not have a `break;` clause. Control falls into the next clause and finally into the `default` statement.
- **Major:** your show confusion between `char` arrays and single char variables: `strcpy(string, x);` should not even compile.
- Your method for parsing `-l` or `-s` is very convoluted and probably erroneous. You should use character literals.
- You do not need a double loop to find the smallest or the largest element in an array. A single loop suffices, and the `printf` statement should be outside the loop. `max` and `min` are uninitialized, the loops invoke undefined behavior.
- the title says *using `atoi()`*: if this was your assignment, you should not use `scanf()`.

Here is a simplified version:

```
int main(void) {
    char option[3], buffer[32];
    int i, min, max, value;

    min = max = 0;
    if (scanf("%2s", option) == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 && scanf("%31s", buffer) == 1; i++) {
            value = atoi(buffer);
            if (i == 0) {
                min = max = value;
            } else {
                if (min > value)
                    min = value;
                if (max < value)
                    max = value;
            }
        }
        if (!strcmp(option, "-l")) {
            printf("output: The largest number is %d\n", max);
            return 0;
        } else
        if (!strcmp(option, "-s")) {
            printf("output: The smallest number is %d\n", min);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("You have entered an invalid option, try again next time.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @YellowBird: your question title is *Finding largest and smallest numbers using atoi* yet all numeric conversions are done with `scanf`. The way you use `atoi` does not make sense.  Are you supposed to use `atoi`?

Comment: @YellowBird: OK, I updated the code above to use `atoi` to convert the strings read by `scanf` into numbers.

Comment: And why do you use 3 as your size for the option array?

Comment: @YellowBird:  the option array receives a 2 byte string `-l` or `-s`.  You need an extra byte for the `'\0'`

Comment: @YellowBird: For the buffer array, I used an arbitrary length of 32, `scanf` reads a string delimited by whitespace into `buffer` and `atoi(buffer)` converts the string to the integer it represents.